# Run button isn't working in Pycharm. How do I fix this?

Tags: python, pycharm

In PyCharm the run button is in grey, not allowing me to click it to run my code. Is there a simple fix to this?

Comment: show your python code

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because your interpreter isn't configured for your current file. You can run your file easily by right clicking on the tab in which your file is open, and then selecting "run (name of file)". It will automatically configure that file, so you can use the run button after that to run it. Remember that you'll have to do this for every new file that you open.

Answer (score 0):

In order to run things, you should configure few things:

- you must select which is the *root directory* of your code: some people uses directly the root directory (but for test, docs, and eventually also utils (and likes), so also in this case you must select all roots), some people put code in a directory named *src* or as the package name.  In this case you should select it (left click on project panel [the panels with the file and folder list], *Mark directory as...* menu item).
- you should have a default python environment for the project (or some available environments). Go to *Settings*, *Project: ...*, *Project environment*
- Then you should configure the run option. Usually it is on left from run button. Click it, and add a run setting: at minimum you should select which file should be run (and the environment, if you didn't yet have a default environment for your project). Later you can configure more suffs, as you like.

There are also other possible reasons, e.g. wrong extension, really bad formatted file, etc., which could hit new programmers. But in such case, we must have more information. Try with a very simple example, e.g. just one line: `print("Hello World")`, to know that the above 3 steps are correct.